Unable to solve an analytic integration
I have been trying to do an analytical integration of the following function with respect to s:
-((3.26485*10^-10 (s-11130.3) Sqrt[-5512.63 +0.25 s+3.03863*10^7/s] Sqrt[s-4 m^2] (12. m^4-4. m^2 s+s^2))/m^4)

After some time, Mathematica shows $Aborted. How can I resolve this issue?

Not sure what makes you think/believe/know that a closed-form expression exists. Honestly, I am not even sure why I tried this calculation without any justification for the existence of a solution.
You want an analytic integration, but you allow for floating numbers. Replace by abstract constants, e.g $x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n$ and try again.
If you run
-((x1 (s - x2) Sqrt[-x3 + x4 s + x5/s] Sqrt[
       s - 4 m^2] (x6  m^4 - x7  m^2 s + s^2))/m^4) // 
 Integrate[#, s] &

you get a very long result. At the end you can set the various $x$'s to their numerical values.
Finally, and in order to be thorough in case people just want to copy-paste the output of the integration I am attempting to present the result below

Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 103199.


I sometimes wrap or rationalize real coefficients in Mma.SE Q&A:foo = Integrate[-((3.26485*10^-10 (s - 11130.3) Sqrt[-5512.63 + 0.25 s + 3.03863*10^7/s] Sqrt[s - 4 m^2] (12. m^4 - 4. m^2 s + s^2))/m^4) /. {p_Real /; p - Rationalize[p, 10^-4] == 0 :> Rationalize[p, 10^-4], p_Real :> c[p]} // Echo, s]. One can then use foo /. c -> Identity to get the "Real" answer. The second argument of Rationalize forces a rational number and limits the size of the denominator. Simply wrapping with p_Real :> c[p] is easiest on me, but fewer symbolic parameters is usually easier on Integrate. (+1)

@MichaelE2 That's a very good point. Thanks for the explanation!
